# White deposit in tung oil

Tags: finishing, tung-oil

What could this white deposit be in this little bottle of Tung oil? Does this affect the oil? Should I take any measure?

[image]

Comment: I presume "ulei de tung" means "tung oil" so this could be pure tung oil and not a mixed finish with a misleading name like the infamous "Tung Oil Finish" sold in the US (which contains no tung oil). Anyway, I don't use tung but occasionally any natural oil can have some sort of cloudy or small clumps of pale residue (often seen in extra-virgin olive oil for example) but generally this is related to lower temperatures and I presume it isn't cold there!

Comment: @Graphus, yes you are right, "ulei de tung" means "tung oil" and it is pure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is pure raw tung oil* this could be nothing at all to be concerned with, occasional clouding is just something natural to raw oils. But as I say in my Comment above you do generally see it only when the oil gets cold so I don't know why you're seeing it now.

I think ideally you should try to return this bottle to the shop and get a replacement that isn't cloudy. While you're there look at their stock of this oil and see if some bottles are clear and some are cloudy, which would be perfectly normal variation for a natural product.

If getting a replacement is not possible I would try warming the bottle in a bowl of warm water (about the temperature of hot bath water) and seeing if the cloudiness goes away. If the oil does clear I *think* you should have nothing to worry about using the oil but I have no experience with this in finishing oils, only in cooking oils where cloudiness is irrelevant.

---

*Processed oils don't exhibit this problem if it's what I think it is.

Comment: Thanks, will try warming it. I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: Welcome, hope it helps. About the downvote, members are free to downvote any Answer they think isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's like honey crystallizing when it sits too long.  Just warm it up and mix it. It will turn back into oil.

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I already used it and it performed well, without getting to apply this advice but I will keep it in mind for the future! :-)